# When an ExecutorLostFailure occurs in spark, how is the data handled in the executor?

Tags: apache-spark, memory, executor

I have a question about Spark.

Even though ExecutorLostFailure occurred in Spark (some tasks showed failed), the whole app ran fine.

I got an error message like "Container killed by YARN for exceeding memory limits.", but the data output was fine.

In this case, I wonder if the result of the data was completely output or if the result was calculated except for the data of the executor where the error occurred.

Can anyone answer this?